How to disable GitHub comments in IntelliJ Idea?
I have a lot of comments in source code in IntelliJ Idea from GitHub.
How can I hide all the comments or disable it at all? For example because of these comments, especially from GitHub-actions it is very difficult to read my code.
I can not find option in Idea to disable it

I think you mean the "hints" that IDEA gives on some things, as described here. I don't know which one specifically you don't like, but with that name you should be able to find the appropriate setting.

If you are viewing the PR from the PR view, you can click on settings and hide comments:

If you are speaking about comments present directly in editor,

